# How to plot moving figure in matlab

Tags: matlab

How I can make an animation like Fig. 3.2: in the following [link](http://www.physics.cit.ie/photonics/photonic_device_dynamics_group/Techniques.html)

```
clc;clear all;
x=[1 1.2 1.4 2 3 4 5 7 9 10];
y=[2.8 7.6 10.9 12.3 15.0 21 12.3 14.5 42.4 47.7  ];
plot(x,y)
```

Comment: Do you want to make a movie out of it or do you need only the vizualisation in the figure window? Also can you at least post the equations you want to animate and things like the time and steps

Comment: I need to know a general instruction, but I will add a simple program

Answer (score 3):

As discussed [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/animation.html), there are multiple ways to Animate Plots. You can create animated sequences with MATLAB® graphics in three different ways:

1. Save a number of different pictures and play them back as a movie.
2. Continually erase and redraw the objects on the screen, making incremental changes with each redraw.
3. Redefine the XData, YData, ZData, and/or CData plot object properties, optionally linking them to data sources (workspace variables) and updating the properties via calls to refreshdata.

Check out the following example:

```
c = -pi:.04:pi;
cx = cos(c);
cy = -sin(c);
figure('color','white');
axis off, axis equal
line(cx, cy, 'color', [.4 .4 .8],'LineWidth',3);
title('See Pythagoras run!','Color',[.6 0 0])
hold on
x = [-1 0 1 -1];
y =   [0 0 0 0];
ht = area(x,y,'facecolor',[.6 0 0]);
for j = 1:length(c)
    x(2) = cx(j);
    y(2) = cy(j);
    set(ht,'XData',x)
    set(ht,'YData',y)
    drawnow
end
```